# Pop out transition animation

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, transition, swift-protocols

I'm trying to implement the pop in/out transition animation found in this git repo: https://github.com/freedom27/PopInAndOutCollectionViewTransition

The code is meant for a UICollecitonView, however, I have a UIViewController that has a UiCollectionView embedded within it. Due to this, I keep getting an error with my Protocol:

```
protocol CollectionPushAndPoppable {
    var sourceCell: UICollectionViewCell? { get }
    var collectionView: UICollectionView? { get }
    var view: UIView! { get }
}
```

The error essentially says that my ViewController does not conform to the protocol.

```
extension CollectionViewController: CollectionPushAndPoppable {}
```

This line is giving me the error.

How do I fix the protocol so that it conforms to CollectionView within my UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

To conform to a protocol, your object needs to implement all the functions and properties. In this case, you need to add those properties to your `CollectionViewController`. If your `CollectionViewController` is a `UIViewController`, it already has a `view` property.

```
extension CollectionViewController: CollectionPushAndPoppable {

    var sourceCell: UICollectionViewCell? {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }

    var collectionView: UICollectionView? {
        return myViewController
    }

}
```

You can learn more about protocols in the official Swift documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html